# Python shows access denied when trying to fetch data from a website using API

Tags: python, json

I am trying to extract data from a website. In their documentation, they provided this code example below:

```
curl --request GET \
   --url https://api.helloworld.com/v2/year-groups \
   --header 'auth-token: {{token}}'
```

Then, I have tried to transfer it to python with the following code:

```
import requests

params = {"words": 10, "paragraphs": 1, "format": "json"}

response = requests.get(f"https://api.helloworld.com/v2/year-groups/", params=params,
 headers={
   "url": "https://api.helloworld.com/v2/year-groups",
   "auth-token": "d34o301h55154gdaf2cab9e6828bw97d5c3a5acc4c2418f3c5000bkcpa76dam0"
 }
)

print(type(response.json()))
print(response.json())
```

It shows access denied every time I try to connect.What am I getting wrong.

Comment: not sure if this is important but in your code you're using api version v2 and v4

Comment: I changed it, but the problem is unrelated because I am using real website and API with v2, but it still shows the error @IFeel3

Comment: Why do you have the `url` also in the headers? The curl command only has the auth token in the header.